# passing lat and long as url arguments

Tags: javascript, php, url, arguments

I started using the API tool and my map needs to be dynamically changed by passing arguments with the URL, here is my URL, and below is the code which doesn't work. The PHP part of retrieving the arguments works, but transferring those into JS variables doesn't, The "mylat" is the example that doesn't work

hope someone can help me,
Thanks

http://www.beleuramyhome.org.au/myvillaloc.php?urllat=-38.22173&urllong=145.0732905&urlvilla=177

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var map;

  var mylat   = <?php echo json_encode($urllat); ?>; //-38.22173;
  var mylong  = 145.0732905;
  var myvilla = '177'; 

  function initMap() 
  {
    var myLatLng = {lat: mylat, lng: mylong};
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: myLatLng,
      zoom: 18,mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });
```

========================= RESOLVED ==== With PHP+Javascript

```
<?php
      $file_handle = fopen("villaloc.csv", "r");
      $villa = $_GET['villa'];

      // if visitor wants to start from their current location
      $mylat   = $_GET['mylat'];
      $mylong  = $_GET['mylong'];
      $start   = $_GET['start'];
      $walk    = $_GET['walk'];

      $foundrecord = 0;
      while (!feof($file_handle) ) 
      {
        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 128);

        if ($line_of_text[0] == $villa) 
        {
            $foundrecord = 1;
            break;
        }       
      }
      fclose($file_handle);

      if($foundrecord == 0)
      {
        /* Redirect browser */
        header("Location: https://squadron-125.org.il/villanotfound.html");

        /* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
        exit;  
      }       
    ?>

    <script>

      var loricket = 0;

      var VillaNo = parseFloat(<?php echo $line_of_text[0] ?>);
      var mylat   = parseFloat(<?php echo $line_of_text[1] ?>); 
      var mylong  = parseFloat(<?php echo $line_of_text[2] ?>);
          loricket = parseInt(<?php echo $line_of_text[3] ?>);
```

Comment: plz remove json_encode in mylat variable. hope that will work.

Comment: The code your are using to retrieve the urllat , is it working fine?? <?php echo json_encode($urllat); ?> this code gives you -38.22173; output?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_GET` is get value from query string

Also your latitude and longitude is string as it came from URL query string
try to convert it to float like below

```
 var map;

  var mylat   = parseFloat(<?php echo $_GET['urllat'] ?>); //-38.22173;
  var mylong  = parseFloat(<?php echo $_GET['urllong'] ?>);
  var myvilla = '177'; 

  function initMap() 
  {
    var myLatLng = {lat: mylat, lng: mylong};
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: myLatLng,
      zoom: 18,mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });
```

Comment: Hi sumit, Thanks for your help, but it is not working, the page loads empty http://www.beleuramyhome.org.au/myvillaloc.php?urllat=-38.22173&urllong=145.0732905

Answer (score 0):

If you are reloading the same page (running the same page after passing arguments to the url) use **$_GET** method to retrieve the latitude and longitude

```
var mylat   = parseFloat(<?php echo $_GET['urllat'] ?>);
var mylong  = parseFloat(<?php echo $_GET['urllong'] ?>);
```

Using ***parseFloat*** will acuallty converts the php output to floating point

If this doesn't work or if you are sending the url details to another page then use the following

```
<?php 
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //get the url 
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query); 
?> 
var mylat   = <?php echo $query['urllat']; ?>;
var mylong  = <?php echo $query['urllong']; ?>;
```

Hope this may solve the issue.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thanks for your suggestion, but it is NOT working, see for yourself , the page loads empty... http://www.beleuramyhome.org.au/myvillaloc.php?urllat=-38.22173&urllong=145.0732905

Comment: You have error in js file. check the console and remove the error

Comment: Thanks, this works fine for me: var mylat   = parseFloat(<?php echo $_GET['urllat'] ?>);